# Laravel Form Model

Tags: php

My `form.blade.php` is sth like

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'title :', ['class' => 'awesome']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('product[title]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('description', 'description : ', ['class' => 'awesome']) !!}
{!! Form::text('product[description]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

```
<div id="phone" class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('reference_id1', 'reference_id1 : ', ['class' =>    'awesome']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('product[reference_id1]', null, ['class' => 'form-     control']) !!}
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('category_id', 'category_id : ', ['class' => 'awesome'])    !!}
        {!! Form::select('category[]', $categories,null, ['class' =>      'form-       control', 'multiple']) !!}
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('color', 'color : ', ['class' => 'awesome']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('feature[0][color]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('height', 'height : ', ['class' => 'awesome']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('feature[0][height]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>    `
```

and my `Edit.blade.php` is like

```
{!! Form::model($product,['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['ProductController@update',$product->id]]) !!}
    @include('products.form', ['submitBtn' => 'submit'])
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this my ProductController.php@edit

```
    public function edit($id)
        {
        $product = Product::with('feature')->findOrFail($id);
        $categories = Category::pluck('title','id');
        return view('products.edit')->withProduct($product)->withCategories($categories);
}
```

this is while when i wanna edit a product, the input requests are set empty!!
for instance when i go to http://myLarave/Public/product/2/edit the `title` and other inputs are empty :(
any suggestions?!

Answer (score 0):

In your route.php or web.php depend to the version of your laravel, you can make the arg `{id?}`, for example:

```
Route::get('edit/{id?}', 'ProductController@edit');
```

and in the edit function you can initialize the variable $id=null or empty:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
     if($id != null){
        $product = Product::with('feature')->findOrFail($id);
        $categories = Category::pluck('title','id');
        return view('products.edit')->withProduct($product)->withCategories($categories);
     }
}
```

Comment: I use 

     Route::resource('product', 'ProductController',[
     'names' => ['index' => 'products_path',
                 'show' => 'product_path',
                 'create' => 'create_product_path',
                 'edit' => 'edit_path'],
     ]); 

in my web.php (routes file)

Comment: You can try only to initialize `$id` with empty value `""` or `null` and make all action if  `$id` is not `null` or empty.

Comment: actually my ` $id ` is not empty and thanks a lot for checking id